# Looking for a good resource for building a SP 2007 WSP package in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: deployment, solution-package

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: could you define your question some more? Do you mean tools (eg. WSP Builder), tutorials, reference material,...?

Comment: A resource.  I'm not looking to do it using WSPBuilder, so anything pertaining to creating the structure for a SP 2007 site on Visual Studio 2010 would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 doesn't support SharePoint 2007 (at least from the perspective of using any of the templates, designers or auto-packaging tools. You are going to have to create your solution the exact same way we did with VS2008, either using a tool like WSPBuilder to help automate some of the tedium, or doing it all from scratch.

Here is a blog post on building a SharePoint 2007 WSP manually.

http://geekswithblogs.net/evgenyblog/archive/2008/01/27/118966.aspx

Personally, I would use WSPBuilder :)